# My web application stops running when connected to mongodb atlas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

In local mongodb is running when i connect to mongodb atlas it is not connecting and there is no errors.

```
 const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
 const uri = "mongodb+srv://NaveenS:naveen@frozenexpression- 
 jiptd.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
 const client = new MongoClient(uri, {useNewUrlParser: true, 
 useUnifiedTopology: true} );
 client.connect(err => {
    const collection = client.db("yelp_camp").collection("campgrounds");
    client.close();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

In `uri` your database name is `test` and you trying to connect `'yelp_camp'` so write both same and try again.

Comment: I tried using same name ,it's not working same issue